# Test iPhone App on physical iPhone rather than simulator

Tags: iphone

I've just made a basic Hello World app for the iPhone. Compiling and running works fine for iPhone Simulator. But now I'd like to put it on my real physical iPhone, to test it. Is there any way to do this, or do I have to pay $100, put it in the app store and download it (with the chance Apple doesn't like it and just deletes it (what happened to Google Latitude too))?

Thanks in advance.

Nope, I'll not jailbreak it.

Comment: If your phone is jailbroken, you can follow this [tutorial](http://www.alexwhittemore.com/?p=270). It worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you have an iPhone developer's account, you can install a provisioning profile on your iPhone which allows to deploy your own applications to it. You'll have to pay the fee to Apple, though.

Answer (score 0):

No. Transfering it to any iPhone for beta testing requires access to the online iPhone Developers Portal. You'll only get in there and get to generate the certificates with a developers licence.

Answer (score -2):

AFAIK you can not transfer your self-developed tool to your own iPhone. At least, that's what I've read...